# Flameshot won't copy /paste does not work in Wayland / KDE Plasma

Tags: kde, wayland

I am trying to use **Flameshot** in Plasma under Wayland, and I encounter a problem where **copy/paste does not work**.

> Flameshot v11.0.0 (11.0.0-2 Debian)
> Compiled with Qt 5.15.2

I can take a screenshot.
I can save it on disk.
But I cannot copy/paste it, be it with Ctrl+C or the copy icon.

Do you see the same problem, and is there a workaround ?
(except save files everywhere on my disk :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, flameshot can run fine under Wayland, but the Ubuntu package does not set the right flags when building.

There is an indepth discussion here on the project's bug tracker: https://github.com/flameshot-org/flameshot/issues/2848

And also a solution, provided as an easy to run script here: https://github.com/flameshot-org/flameshot/issues/2848#issuecomment-1270589109

This is the script, and it works like a charm (for me :-) ):

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

rm -rf build
mkdir -p build
cd build

sudo apt install devscripts equivs libkf5guiaddons-dev -y
sudo mk-build-deps -t'apt-get -y' -ir flameshot

apt source flameshot
SRC_DIR=`ls | cut -f1 | head -n1`

pushd ${SRC_DIR}
sed -i 's/-DFLAMESHOT_ABOUT_DEB_VERSION/-DUSE_WAYLAND_CLIPBOARD=1 -DFLAMESHOT_ABOUT_DEB_VERSION/' debian/rules
EMAIL=nobody@email.com dch -n ''
debuild -i -j -us -uc
popd

sudo apt purge flameshot-build-deps devscripts equivs libkf5guiaddons-dev --auto-remove -y

sudo dpkg -i flameshot_*.deb
rm -rf ../build
```

Answer (score 0):

Clipboard management is different under Wayland than under Xorg. Apparently, your application was not updated to work correctly under Wayland. Until the application is adapted to also provide this function under Wayland, your workaround will be to use another screenshot tool, if this copy/paste functionality is important to you. Another workaround may be to abandon Wayland and log in to a session on Xorg instead.